# jQuery validator does not return expected result

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox for age. When the form is submitted, I would like to check from the client side whether the value in the textbox is greater than 18 and show a message if the age is not greater than 18.

The problem that I have right now, my custom validator shows the message when I type text and not showing at all when I type numbers below 18. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my custom validator:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.validator.addMethod('ageGreaterEighteen', function(value){
        return parseFloat(value) > 0;
      }, 'Age has to be greater than 18');

      $.validator.addMethod("textOnly", function(value) {
        return !/[0-9]+/.test(value);
      }, "Alpha Characters Only.");

      $("#TestForm").validate({
        rules: {
          txtName: {
            required: true,
            textOnly: true
          },
          txtAge: {
            required: true,
            ageGreaterEighteen: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          txtName: {
            required: "* Required",
            textOnly: "Please enter text only"
          },
          txtAge: {
            required: "* Required",
            ageGreaterEighteen: "Age has to be greater than 18!"
          }
        }
      });
    })
</script>
```

here is my form:

```
<form id="TestForm">
    <label for="txtName">Name: </label><br />
    <input name="txtName" type="text" id="txtFirstName" /><br />
    <label for="txtAge">Age: </label><br />
    <input name="txtAge" type="text" id="txtAge" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `return parseFloat(value) > 0;` be `return parseFloat(value) > 18;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
  $.validator.addMethod('ageGreaterEighteen', function(value){
    return parseFloat(value) > 0;
  }, '
```

Which should be

```
  $.validator.addMethod('ageGreaterEighteen', function(value){
    return parseFloat(value) > 18;
  }, '
```